# discord.py (Python 3.6.5 Discord) says 'invalid syntax' on 'def' everytime I try and run my Discord bot

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code --

```
import os, discord, asyncio, requests, threading, platform, requests, json, 
logging, random, pickle, time
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.utils import get


BOT_PREFIX = ("?", "!", "~", "`", "/", "-", "*", "^", "%", "$", "#", "&", "|")
TOKEN = "INSERT TOKEN"  # Get at discordapp.com/developers/applications/me

client = Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)

@client.command(name = '8ball',
            brief="Answers a yes/no question.",
            description="Answers from the beyond.",
            aliases=['eight_ball', 'eightball', '8-ball'],
            pass_context=True)
async def eight_ball(context):
possible_responses = [
    'That is a resounding **no**',
    'It is **not** looking likely',
    'It is **quite** possible',
    '**Definitely**',
    'Definitely... **not**',
    '**Yes**',
    '**No way**',
    '**Of course!**',
    'I have spoken to the gods... They have said **Yes!** :smile:',
    'I have spoken to the gods... They have said **No!** :rage:',
    '**Maybe?**',
    '**Not at all!**',
    '**Not** in a **million** years.',
    '**You bet ;)**',

]
await client.say(random.choice(possible_responses) + ", " + context.message.author.mention)


@client.command(brief = 'Rolls 2 dice from 1-6',
            description = 'Rolls 2 dice',
            pass_context=True)
async def dice(context):
possible_responses = [
    '**2**',
    '**3**',
    '**4**',
    '**5**',
    '**6**',
    '**7**',
    '**8**',
    '**9**',
    '**10**',
    '**11**',
    '**12**',

]
await client.say(random.choice(possible_responses) + ", " + context.message.author.mention)

@client.command(name = 'dice3',
            category = 'Fun & Games',
            brief = 'Rolls 1 dice from 1-3',
            description = 'Rolls 1 dice',
            pass_context=True)
async def dice(context):
possible_responses = [
    '**1**',
    '**2**',
    '**3**',

]
await client.say(random.choice(possible_responses) + ", " + context.message.author.mention)

@client.command(brief = 'Deletes any number of messages you would like...',
            description = '!purge <number>',
            pass_context = 1) # enter ( ./purge <number> ) to delete a large num of messages.
async def purge(context, number : int):
    deleted = await client.purge_from(context.message.channel, limit = number)
    await client.send_message(context.message.channel, 'Deleted {} message(s)!'.format(len(deleted))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.content.startswith('!cool'):
    await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Who is **cool**? Type `!name` @(user)')

    def check(msg):
        return msg.content.startswith('!name')

    message = await client.wait_for_message(author=message.author, check=check)
    name = message.content[len('!name'):].strip()
    await client.send_message(message.channel, '{} is **cool** indeed'.format(name))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.content.startswith('!greet'):
    await client.send_message(message.channel, '**Say** `hello`')
    msg = await client.wait_for_message(author=message.author, content='hello')
    await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Hello.')

@client.command(category = 'Facts',
            brief = 'Shows the price of Bitcoin',
            description = '!bitcoin',
            pass_context=True)
async def bitcoin():
url = 'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/BTC.json'
response = requests.get(url)
value = response.json()['bpi']['USD']['rate']
await client.say("**Bitcoin price is: $**" + value)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.content.startswith('!start'):
    await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Type `!stop` **4 times.**')
    for i in range(4):
        msg = await client.wait_for_message(author=message.author, content='!stop')
        fmt = '**{} left to go...**'
        await client.send_message(message.channel, fmt.format(3 - i))

    await client.send_message(message.channel, '**Good job!** :smiley:')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
await client.change_presence(game=Game(name="with nothing"))
print("Logged in as " + client.user.name)


async def list_servers():
await client.wait_until_ready()
while not client.is_closed:
    print("Current servers:")
    for server in client.servers:
        print(server.name)
    await asyncio.sleep(600)


client.loop.create_task(list_servers())
client.run("INSERT TOKEN")
```

Can someone please help me I don't understand why this is happening. I'm just trying to have some fun and mess around with my friends but this keeps happening, and I am unable to run the bot. If you can help me, that would very much be appreciated :D. I am new to coding, so that might be the reason as there may be some very obvious mistakes that I can not find. Please help me :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python \[Invalid syntax\] with async def](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43948454/python-invalid-syntax-with-async-def)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the *context* from your function attributes

```
async def eight_ball(context):
```

/

```
async def eight_ball():
```

> v0.15.0 New Features
>
> > For the command extension, the following changed:
> >
> > ```
> > Context is no longer slotted to facilitate setting dynamic attributes.
> > ```