# Beta: Github Codespace, was getting SynatxError, now resolved; however now receiving ImportError

Tags: python, discord.py, python-3.10, github-codespaces

**EDIT:**
After following xcodz-dot's suggestion, while it was helpful and I believed it has fixed one problem, I recieved an exception in `client.py`. Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspaces/[repo_name]/resource.py", line 5, in <module>
    from discord_components import DiscordComponents, ButtonStyle, Button
  File "/opt/python/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord_components/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .client import *
  File "/opt/python/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord_components/client.py", line 3, in <module>
    from discord import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'Guild' from 'discord' (/opt/python/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/__init__.py)
```

Is this a seperate issue or is it in direct causation of changing `asyncio.async` to `getattr(asyncio, "async")` in both compat.py and compatibility.py?

Please help me, thx :)

===============================================================

**BELOW: OLD QUESTION, LIKELY RESOLVED**

I am using Github Codespaces, and in the process of programming my bot, when trying to import discord_components, a SyntaxError is raised. Traceback (bash terminal, linux vm):

```
@[username]➜ /workspaces/[repo_name] (main ✗) $ /opt/python/latest/bin/python /workspaces/SineBot/resource.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspaces/[repo_name]/resource.py", line 4, in <module>
    from discord_components import DiscordComponents, ButtonStyle, Button
  File "/opt/python/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord_components/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .client import *
  File "/opt/python/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord_components/client.py", line 3, in <module>
    from discord import (
  File "/opt/python/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .client import Client, AppInfo, ChannelPermissions
  File "/opt/python/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 38, in <module>
    from .state import ConnectionState
  File "/opt/python/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/state.py", line 36, in <module>
    from . import utils, compat
  File "/opt/python/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/compat.py", line 32
    create_task = asyncio.async
                          ^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have tried all soloutions in [create_task = asyncio.async: SyntaxError: invalid syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51196568/create-task-asyncio-async-syntaxerror-invalid-syntax), except for downgrading to Py3.5 and using `rewrite.zip` (because it doesn't even exist), but there are functionalities in Py3.10 that I need, and downgrading would be a nightmare, if not, impossible. Note that `discord.py` works on my local machine.

Here is `combat.py` for reference:

```py
...
import concurrent.futures
import asyncio

try:
    create_task = asyncio.ensure_future
except AttributeError:
    create_task = asyncio.async # -> where the exception is happening


try:
    run_coroutine_threadsafe = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe
except AttributeError:
...
```

The same exception is raised when `discord.py` is imported (before `discord_components`).

Please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python 3.10, `async` is a keyword just like any other keyword such as `while`, `for`, etc... So you cannot write it like that. As far as I can see you are trying to be backwards compatible so you can use `getattr` builtin function which will resolve the error

```py
...
import concurrent.futures
import asyncio

try:
    create_task = asyncio.ensure_future
except AttributeError:
    create_task = getattr(asyncio, "async") # -> where the exception is happening


try:
    run_coroutine_threadsafe = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe
except AttributeError:
...
```

Comment: Hi @xcodz-dot, thanks, but it for some reason didn't work. While it did resolve the issue in compat.py, it raised an exception in `/opt/python/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/websockets/compatibility.py`, the same one. I tried changing that to `getattr(asyncio, "async")` too, but then I got `ImportError: cannot import name 'Guild' from 'discord' (/opt/python/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/__init__.py)`. Is this a seperate issue, or one caused by changing `asyncio.async` to `getattr(asyncio, "async")`?

Comment: That sounds just another issue, because import error likely means that their is something missing. As your question said, I just fixed the SyntaxError without really messing with other things. If you would like, you can open another Question for afformentioned issue. I am not experienced with discord.py and thus only focused on fixing error message.